# Level 2 (related model) scope over REST - strongloop api

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I found in the documentation that [scopes](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Scopes) enable you to specify commonly-used queries that you can reference as method calls on a model. Below i have a `categories` model. I am trying to create scopes that applies to the relation with model `games`. Unfortunately the below does nothing. How can I get scopes to apply to relation as shown below?

`GET /Categories/{id}/games` - This gets all games

*common/models/category.json*

```
"relations": {
    "categories": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "game",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
},
```

*/common/models/game.json*

```
 "scopes": {
    "mature": {"where": {"mature": true}}
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "category": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "category",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to get the data through endpoing: `/Categories/{id}/games/mature`

Table schema:

```
catgories

category_name       category_id 
-------------       -----------
fighting            1001
racing              1002
sports              1003

games

game_id         game_name           category_id     mature
-----------     ------------        -----------     --------------
13KXZ74XL8M     Tekken              10001           true
138XZ5LPJgM     Forza               10002           false
```

Comment: where does mature property belong? game or category?

Comment: @Anoop.P.A  it belongs to category

Comment: Out of the box, you can do a REST query to achieve the results you want, if not the endpoint. `Categories/{id}?filter[include]=games&filter[where][mature]=true` https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter

Comment: @conradj I dont want to expose the rest query through the endpoint url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loopback api is based on `swagger` and `scopes` is a new concept in loopback.

Currently it doesn't have support for related methods i.e. you cannot access it from a related model i.e `category` (in your case) but only from model where the `scope` is defined i.e. `game`.

Thus you can achieve what you want right now using remote methods.

**By Using `Remote Methods`**. [Loopback Remote Methods](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+methods)

> common/models/category.js add the following lines.

```
module.exports = function(Category) {

    Category.mature = function(id, filter, callback) {
        var app = this.app;
        var Game = app.models.Game;
        if(filter === undefined){
             filter = {};
        }

        filter.where  = filter.where || {};

        filter.where.categoryId =  id;
        filter.where.mature = true;

        Game.find(filter, function(err, gameArr) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            console.log(gameArr);
            callback(null, gameArr);
        });
    }

    Category.remoteMethod(
        'mature', {
            accepts: [{
                arg: 'id',
                type: 'number',
                required: true
            },
            {
                arg: 'filter',
                type: 'object',
                required: false
            }
            ],
            // mixing ':id' into the rest url allows $owner to be determined and used for access control
            http: {
                path: '/:id/games/mature',
                verb: 'get'
            },
            returns: {
                arg: 'games',
                type: 'array'
            }
        }
    );

};
```

> Now in your common/models/category.json
>     Add this to your ACL property.

```
.....
.....
"acls": [
  {
     "principalType": "ROLE",
     "principalId": "$everyone",
     "permission": "ALLOW",
     "property": "mature"
  }
]
```

Now you can get all your game of mature type by `get method`
 `http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/categories/:id/games/mature`

Or you can also try the API from `loopback-explorer` now.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student `filter` is not build-in supported for `loopback remote methods` but you can modified your code to make it support.
Check the answer I have modified now it supports `filters`

Comment: Could you provide guidance with [this new follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232662/querying-from-models-with-hasmanythrough-relations-strongloop-api)