# Querying from models with HasManyThrough relations - strongloop api

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

This is a follow up to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101531/level-2-related-model-scope-over-rest-strongloop-api). Currently, the api can query from the `category` and `game` model which share a relation. For example, through this endpoint `/Categories/1001/games/mature` I can list all games of `fighting` category that have `mature` set to `true`.  However, I have included a third model `gameInfo` from db table `game_info`. Since, I want to fetch the information from those three tables, i have included a through model named `gamesCategoriesBridge` from db table `games_categories_bridge`. I followed the guidelines to set [HasManyThrough relations](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations). The issue is that the additional information such as `description` and `publishedDate` doesnt show in the final result. How could I properly set the `remoteMethod` to accomplish the below?

> common/models/category.js

```
module.exports = function(Category) {
Category.mature = function(id, callback) {
    var app = this.app;
    var Game = app.models.Game;
    Game.find({
        "where": {
            categoryId: id,
            mature: true
        }
    }, function(err, gameArr) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        console.log(gameArr);
        callback(null, gameArr);
    });
}

Category.remoteMethod(
    'mature', {
        accepts: [{
            arg: 'id',
            type: 'number',
            required: true
        }],
        // mixing ':id' into the rest url allows $owner to be determined and used for access control
        http: {
            path: '/:id/games/mature',
            verb: 'get'
        },
        returns: {
            arg: 'games',
            type: 'array'
        }
    }
);

};
```

> Table schema:

*catgories*

```
category_name       category_id 
-------------       -----------
fighting            1001
racing              1002
sports              1003
```

*games*

```
game_id         game_name           category_id     mature
-----------     ------------        -----------     --------------
13KXZ74XL8M     Tekken              10001           true
138XZ5LPJgM     Forza               10002           false
```

*game_info*

```
game_id         description                     published_date
-----------     -----------                     --------------                      
13KXZ74XL8M     Published by Namco.             1994
138XZ5LPJgM     Published by Microsoft Studios. 2005
```

*games_categories_bridge*

```
game_id        category_id   
-----------    ----------- 
13KXZ74XL8M    10001   
138XZ5LPJgM    10002
```

Endpoint: `/categories/{id}/games/mature`
Desired Format for API Response:

```
games [ 
{
gameName: 'Tekken', 
gameInfo : 
[
    { 
        description : 'Published by Namco.',
        published_date : '1994'
    }
],
        categorName: 'fighting', 
        categoryId: 1001, 
        mature: true 
}
.....
]
```

Comment: Your desirable API response format have `game_info` property but it shows information related to `category` why is that. Also, I think  you need to redesign the schema of your database. Because using this schema you can achieve what you want but things will get difficult than normal.

Comment: @RobinsGupta, sorry, typo. Corrected the desired API response.

Comment: What is the relation between `games->category model` ? Is each `game` belongs to one `category` or each `game` can have many `category`?

Comment: @RobinsGupta each game can have many category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `hasMany` relation between `game` and `game_info` model

```
//Now inside remote_method.
Category.mature = function(id, callback) {
    var app = this.app;
    var Game = app.models.game;
    Category.findById(id, {}, function(err, category) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        //Now call the Game find method
        Game.find({
            "where": {
                categoryId: id,
                mature: true
            },
            include:'game_info'
        }, function(err, gameArr) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            gameArr.forEach(function(gameObj, index){
                gameObj.categoryName = category.category_name;

            });
            callback(null, gameArr);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: For the first `where` I am getting error `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'category_id id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student there was a typo  I have edited it check.

Comment: Have you been able to incorporate social login authentication with loopback? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549717/social-logins-authentication-through-loopback-passport