# Adding pagination cursor and additional features to endpoint result

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Strongloop api has been great to work with right out of the box. However I am currently trying to make some customizations. I am trying to add to the `category` model a remote method that returns along with the endpoint data the following: `perPage`, `total`, `paging`(shown below in more details). For `paging` the `before` and `after` are parameters based on `gameId`. `limit` will default to `5` if value is `null` or greater than `5`. What would be the best way to append to result the previously mentioned?

For example, `http://localhost:3000/api/Categories/1004/games/mature?before=1000053` will return all `gameId` less than `1000053` and `before` all `gameIds` greater than `1000053`.

> common/models/category.js

```
  Category.findById(id, {}, function(err, category){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        //set limit
        if (limit && limit > 5){
          limit = 5;
        }else if(limit === undefined){
          limit = 5;
        }
        //set after cursor
        Games.find({
            "where": {
                categoryId: id,
                mature: true,
                gameId: {gt: after}
            },
            "limit": limit
        }, function(err, gameArr) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, gameArr);
        });
    });
```

Endpoint results for `/Categories/1004/games/mature`

```
{
      “perPage”: 5, //value from limit
      “total”: 5, //total of return items from array
      "data": [
         ... Endpoint data is here
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": 1000057, //last item in array
          "before": 1000053 //first item in array
        },
        "previous": "http://localhost:3000/api/Categories/1004/games/mature?before=1000053" //url for previous
        "next": "http://localhost:3000/api/Categories/1004/games/mature?after=1000057" //url for after
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add results to the response, first change the type of response that the Category.mature remote method returns to an object:

```
Category.remoteMethod('mature', {
  accepts: [
    {arg: 'id', type: 'number', required: true},
    {arg: 'limit',type: 'number',required: false},
    {arg: 'after',type: 'number',required: false},
    {arg: 'before',type: 'number',required: false}   
  ],
  // mixing ':id' into the rest url allows $owner to be determined and used for access control
  http: {
    path: '/:id/games/mature',
    verb: 'get'
  },
  returns: {
    arg: 'games',
    type: 'object' // will be whatever you pass back as 2nd arg to callback()
  }
});
```

Then just add the values you want to the new games object, using your existing gamesArr as the value for `data`, and the values passed in for the limit, before, and after values into the response object as the 2nd argument to the success callback:

```
callback(null, {
  "perPage": limit,
  "total": gameArray.length,
  "data": gameArray,
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": gameArray[gameArray.length-1].game_id, // last game_id in result
      "before": gameArray[0].game_id // first game_id in result
    },
    "previous": "http://localhost:3000/api/Categories/1004/games/mature?before=" + gameArray[0].game_id,
    "next": "http://localhost:3000/api/Categories/1004/games/mature?after=" + gameArray[gameArray.length-1].game_id
  }
})
```

As I mentioned about the multiple Games.find() calls that were overcomplicating the code, you also shouldn't plunk down 3 or 4 copies of that object either. You can wrap the construction of the object in logic, then have a single callback() call to simplify the remote method's I/O management and write less code. Reducing to a single Games.find() call will make sending this result easier.

Also keep an eye out for curly apostrophe characters and tabs vs space indentation (pick one and stick with it, don't mix), it's much easier to help out when your code is constructed and organized with care.

Comment: Added a correction to the before and after cursor ID vars.

Comment: This is perfect, any idea how to manipulate the items inside `gameArray`. For example take `description` and `publishedDate` and placle it inside an additional array `gameInfo`. The result `"gameInfo": {
   "description": "Published by Activision",
      "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with gameInfo? Do you mean manipulate the result objects inside gameArray and put description and publishedDate inside gameInfo inside each game object? You already have access to these fields without the need to add the extra layer of gameInfo. But you could add a gameInfo object to each game object by looping on the gameArray and modifying the objects. Check out the  lodash library and the `map` function, too.

Comment: Yes, will check it out then.

Comment: An additional question about social login authentication through the `passport-component`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549717/social-logins-authentication-through-loopback-passport

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are using the Category model as the entry point, when it seems like you should be using the built-in query methods of the Game model with a filter and limit and offset, full stop. That will allow you to paginate without needing to add all this complexity to support your before/after concept. It's unnecessary. *If your relations are set up correctly, all you need to paginate on games is a Games model query!*

For example, it looks like you need a **paginated list of games that are mature within a specific category**, right? To get a result of 5 games with these criteria, you'd send a json REST API call like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Games?filter=%7B%20%22where%22%3A%20%7B%22mature%22%3Atrue%2C%20%22categoryId%22%3A%201004%7D%2C%20%22offset%22%3A%200%2C%20%22limit%22%3A%205%20%7D
```

That's hard to read because it's encoded, but the underlying filter is constructed like this:

```
{ "where": {"mature":true, "categoryId": 1004}, "offset": 0, "limit": 5 }
```

This will return the following dataset, which is the **first 5 games that are in the 1004 categoryId and also mature**:

```
[
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "CODBlacOps3",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000053,
    "description": "Published by Activision",
    "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Evolve",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000054,
    "description": "Published by Turtle Rock Studios",
    "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Battlefield4",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000055,
    "description": "Published by EA Digital Illusions",
    "publishedDate": "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Rainbow6",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000056,
    "description": "Published by EUbisoft",
    "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Destiny",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000057,
    "description": "Published by Bungie",
    "publishedDate": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

To get the *next page of 5 games*, we would just change the offset to 5, which tells the database to skip the first 5 because we're now on the 2nd page:

```
{ "where": {"mature":true, "categoryId": 1004}, "offset": 5, "limit": 5 }
```

This returns the following result:

```
[
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Wolfenstein",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000058,
    "description": "Published by Bethesda",
    "publishedDate": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "StarWarsBattleFront",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000059,
    "description": "Published by EA DICE",
    "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Test1",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000060,
    "description": "Published by Test1",
    "publishedDate": "2015-12-19T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Test2",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000061,
    "description": "Published by Test2",
    "publishedDate": "2015-12-19T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Test3",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000062,
    "description": "Published by Test3",
    "publishedDate": "2015-12-19T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

The Games are in the order of their game_id by default. No custom remote methods and nested find()s necessary!

If you wanted to order the list alphabetically, you could also add the `order` filter, and set it to `"order": "gameName ASC"`:

```
{ "where": {"mature":true, "categoryId": 1004}, "offset": 0, "limit": 5, "order": "gameName ASC" }
```

Which will return a new (page 1 because I set offset back to 0) array of games, ordered alphabetically by `gameName`:

```
[
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Battlefield4",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000055,
    "description": "Published by EA Digital Illusions",
    "publishedDate": "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "CODBlacOps3",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000053,
    "description": "Published by Activision",
    "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Destiny",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000057,
    "description": "Published by Bungie",
    "publishedDate": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Evolve",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000054,
    "description": "Published by Turtle Rock Studios",
    "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "mature": true,
    "gameName": "Rainbow6",
    "categoryId": 1004,
    "gameId": 1000056,
    "description": "Published by EUbisoft",
    "publishedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

The way I was able to get this result so quickly was by using the API Explorer. I forked your project, changed the DB connection values to match my local server, started it up and then went to `http://0.0.0.0/explorer/#!/Games/Games_find` and then played with different `filter` values on the Games model:

[image]

Comment: The thing is I dont really want to fully expose all these `filter` options through the url. For that same reason, I hard coded the `limit` but still gave the option to have a limit set that doesnt exceed `x` value. I have been following up on the pattern of how others(fb, instagram, youtube) have set up their api. My main concern is some advice on how to add to the end results these additional values `perPage`, `total`, etc

Comment: Still, there is some much cleaner code you could write for the custom Category.findById() you are currently running with. There is no need to have 3 separate Games.find() calls. The logic should focus on constructing the filters, then run a single Games.find() query. As for your real question, I'll add an answer for how to add the extra data in the response.

Comment: You are right, I need to focus on simplifying that part.

Comment: Just a little exercise here, I refactored to remove the complexity of the cursors. All you need to ask for is # of games per page, and the page number. I don't know your full requirements, but I don't think items per page (limit) and page number (limit * pagenumber = offset) for the games is exposing too many filter options, and it lets you concentrate on pagination, not the cursor concept. See https://github.com/notbrain/games-strongloop-api/blob/master/common/models/category.js

Comment: You been very helpful. However, it seems i like i need to guess the page number if there is a next page or not. Overall, I am trying to duplicate something similar to this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api (within webpage page search keyword `pagination`)

Comment: I see. What is the underlying reason you need to use cursors? Just the exercise of replicating cursor based pagination? The Facebook API is way more complex than simple SQL queries on the backend, and also much more optimized for cursor based resultsets (the custom db they have probably handles them). But for your purposes it just means you'll have to add queries to make sure next and previous links make sense, and then construct the result object accordingly (aka do not include previous or next cursors if they do not point to anything).

Comment: Yes, wanted to see the possibility of replicating their set up. You are right.